1x1 Widget invisible in Samsung launcher at Android 14
If my app on a Samsung device under Android 14 is supposed to provide a 1x1 widget and an app shortcut at the same time, the 1x1 widget is not displayed in the launcher (long press on start screen and "Widgets")
If I increase the widget size to 2x2 in the "widget_info.xml" (minWidth and minHeight to 100dp), the widget is displayed correctly.
If I remove the activity "Shortcut" in the AndroidManifest.xml, the 1x1 widget is displayed correctly.
In the Nova Launcher or at Android <14, there are no problems displaying the shortcut and the 1x1 widget at the same time.
Any suggestions?
AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<application
    <!-- ... -->

    <receiver
        android:name=".WidgetProvider"
        android:label="Test-Widget"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".Shortcut"
        android:label="Test-Shortcut"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>

widget_info.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:updatePeriodMillis="3000"
  android:minWidth="40dp"
  android:minHeight="40dp"
  android:initialLayout="@layout/main"
  android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
  android:configure="com.example.widget_test.Main"
  android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"/>



